# Why word <newline> can't be displayed in wordpress?

Tags: tags

The content is simple.

```
it is a test 
\n=<newline>
```

[image]

The **`<newline>`** can't be displayed after publishing.

[image]

Why it is escaped by tag `<>`?

Comment: Did you try putting it in the "code"? It's the button left of table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These tags will be stripped by WordPress, as if you are inserting a code directly to your post's content.

To add special characters to your post, switch to visual editor, and then click the special character button as shown below:

[image]

Now you can select any character you want from the list.

You can also do this by using text editor. Enter `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>` in text editor, so your phrase will be like:

`&lt;newline&gt;`

These are the HTML entity equivalents for your provided unicode characters.

**PS:** Image's credits goes to [WPBegginer.com](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-special-characters-in-wordpress-posts/)